# Difference between "struct" and "value struct"

Tags: c++-cli

What is the difference between

```
public struct X{
public:
    int A;};
```

and

```
public value struct X{
public:
    int A;};
```

How can I convert one into the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a normal C++ structure.

Using `value struct` creates a C++/CLI value type (a .NET structure).  You typically will want to copy from one to the other manually, though if the memory layout is the same, you can often use things like [`Marshal::PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy the data directly.  Note that this returns a boxed `value struct`, however, so manual copying is often more efficient.